# How can I see source code of .exe soft?

Tags: exe

i have installed on software and i want to see source code 
i try to see source code with 010 editor but i see like this code

[image]

I've been with it for almost a week and I can not find code

I do not understand what code is

Answer (score 2):

Without a disassembler, you're not going to get very far.

`.exe` files are *compiled* programs. The source code is optimized, converted into assembly, and then converted from assembly into hexadecimal machine code long before it ever touches your disk. There is no easy way to read the "source" code of an executable without a disassembler which can generate psuedocode from assembly, and even then, the generated code will have compiler optimizations thrown into the mix, so the source code generated will not be identical to the original source.

The only way to read the actual source code of a compiled executable is if it's compiled with debugging symbols, which should display the source alongside assembly using the right tools. But this must be done at the compile stage, and is impossible to do with just the EXE file you have.

In short, this is impossible unless you can understand assembly, have a disassembler, and are willing to slog through and reconstruct the code by hand.

Comment: its not .exe installer i have download it and click on icon and directly opend it

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's an installer. **All** EXE files are compiled source code. Unless it's some weird trickery (a la the Love2D engine) where the "source" is an interpreted language tacked onto the end of an EXE, you're not going to be able to read the original C or whatever that the EXE is a product of.

Comment: It again **does not matter**. Unless the program is written in .NET or Java or something (plausible on the former, highly unlikely on the latter), **there is no way to extract the original source code without work done by hand**.

Comment: Even with decompiled .NET applications, there will still be compiler optimizations and different variable names. You won't be able to extract the true, original source code, even if it's slightly easier.